# Special character in concatenated sql script causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I save stored procedure code as files and then execute them in several different databases.  I am trying to concatenate multiple files (100's).  Every utility I use seems to create some special characters in the file that cause an error when i execute the script in sql.

Currently, i used

```
type *.sql > script.sql
```

in DOS.  I am getting the following error in many places.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ''.
```

How can I find this character so I can do a find/replace?  Thanks!

Comment: Does it happen with any two sql script files?  If you open the file in notepad, does it look right or do you see a funky block character there?

Comment: If you get this when executing a .sql file **Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1**, please include the actual file here (can also attach if you like, if it's all on one line with no new-lines, that's gonna make it hard to debug no?)  Basically, you should be a) splitting into lines and b) closely analyzing line 1.

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar. Here's the text from batch file `__QuickConcatenate_SQL.bat` that will copy all `*.sql` files in that same folder into a new file:

```
  REM  Concatenate all .sql files into a single file

@ECHO OFF
CLS

COPY  *.sql  __ConcatenatedSQLScripts.sql  /b

ECHO.
PAUSE
```

Note that "/b" parameter. I wrote this a long time ago, I recall including it to prevent the addition of oddball characters--CR, LF, EOF, something like that. (I never could figure out how to control the order that procedures were copied...)

Note also that this only works if the last line in every file is `GO`, followed by CR+LF (e.g. type "GO" and hit enter in SSMS).

Comment: Very likely GO is simply missing from his scripts come to think of it.  Without it, SQL Server may not know where one block ends and another begins.  (Of course, this will affect transaction commit if he's not in auto-commit mode)  PS - I never realized NT Batch copy could concat files!  Who would have thought.  (especially given the usage)

Comment: I ran that script and I got these characters in the resulting file ï»¿/****** Objec

Comment: Are there any "standard" characters in the file? If not, then your .sql files are probably in Unicode. Easy check: open the file in Notepad, do SAVE AS, and see what "type" of file it defaults to. "SAVE AS" standard ascii should fix this.

Comment: ...not that it's bad, no, just that I find non-unicode scripts easier to work with (unless, of course, you require unicode in your stored procedures).